# C# count #times number can be halved

Tags: c#

As per title; I have tried multiple ways I can't seem to get my head around where I'm going wrong. I feel this is as close as I've got, but something still seems scrambled. Can someone help me out on finalising this? (This current code consistently outputs 0).

To clarify; I want the code to be able to read the number inputted by a user and figure out how many times it can be halved before reaching 1.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number to find how many time it can be divided without becoming less than 1");
Int32 DiviNum = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Int32 count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i > 1; i = i / 2)
{
    count++;
}
Console.WriteLine("Number of times " + DiviNum + " is divisible by 2 is " + count);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try rubber-duck debugging. There is a huge logical fault in the current code.

Comment: The number you read in is DiviNum. Where in your code are you trying to divide it?

Comment: Why are you never dividing `DiviNum`, only `i`? Hint: use `while` loop; you don't need `i` at all.

Comment: for (int i = DiviNum;...)

Comment: If you want to do this for large numbers, calculate the log2 for that number.

Comment: Also, a simple problem like this can **easily** be found with very basic debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone. Hans Passant hit this one directly on the head, but can't seem to mark it as the answer. - Query solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is

```
 Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number to find how many time it can be divided without becoming less than 1");
    Int32 DiviNum = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Int32 count = 0;
    for (int i = DiviNum/2 ; i > 1; i = i / 2)
    {
        count++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Number of times " + DiviNum + " is divisible by 2 is " + count);
```